# Use K8s Init Container to copy a an existing file

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I am using this [keycloak image](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/README.md) and trying to find out how I can copy the oracle jdbc driver into the keycloak container.

There are examples using Init Container to create a file but I will need to copy an existing file.
I know where the jdbc file should be copied to, that's in the documentation for the keycloak image file.
What I don't know is where I should get the jdbc file from. Should it be on a disk somewhere in the cluster or should I download it?

Comment: Why not build a custom image adding this driver?

Comment: I prefer building my own image, but you can also use the command argument : command : `wget -O /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/jdbc/main/drive/postgres.jar  http://url-to-jdbc && start-container.sh`, replace start-container.sh by the container startup script.

Comment: Hello. If you're wondering where to put the Oracle JDBC jar, I would say look at putting it in 1) the same directory as another JDBC driver (option a whole directory is loaded in Java programs) or 2) in the path that the server jar is run with.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-oracle.yml), you should put the driver to the directory `/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/jdbc/main/driver`. The driver JAR must be renamed to `ojdbc.jar`.

If you want to use `initContainers` for that, you need to create a volume shared between the init-container and the actual keycloak container, download the driver there and mount it to the appropriate path. More or less something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: jboss/keycloak
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/jdbc/main/driver
              name: driver
          env:
            - name: DB_VENDOR
              value: ORACLE
      initContainers:
        - name: init
          image: alpine
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'wget -o /driver/odbc.jar DRIVER_URL']
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /driver
              name: driver
      volumes:
        - name: driver
```

> Replace `DRIVER_URL` in the command with the actual driver URL

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis as far as I understand the question is: "My problem are that I don't know where I should put JDBC file."

Comment: As I understand it, the question is "how can I download the jar file at startup", not "where should I put the downloaded jar", but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Question was not clear to me, trying to cancel my downvote but I can't (vote is locked in unless the answer is edited),, sorry for this

Comment: I think we need to clarify the question. Is it "the location where I copy the jar?" or is it "how to make an init container copy a file?" @Martin Andersen